# Sqoop: sqoop export DB2 loack

Tags: sqoop

Does sqoop export issue any locks while exporting the data from hive to db2?
What type of lock does it issue? If there is a lock how are these locks released?

I get a validation error as there are parallel sqoop export process running on the same db2 table. Hence, wondering if there are any locks issued and what type of locks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Aavik, DB2 supports locks. There are three types of locks.

```
1. S lock (share)
2. U lock (update)
3. X lock (exclusive)
```

When you scan the table to read the data, for E.g when you do `select * from table where <condition>`, it does a read operation on the table, when it reads the data from the table it applies S lock on the table, meaning other requests can read the data, but cannot update or write.

When you do transactions on the table it applies U lock.

When you insert new data it acquires X lock, meaning it doesn't allow any read operation or update operation.

> So, when you do sqoop export from Hive to DB2 it acquires X lock on
>   the table as it is inserting new records.

When you do sqoop import, it acquires S lock on the table.

This is a very common problem everywhere, you have many options to overcome this issue.

```
1. maintain separate views/Tables for regular transactions.
2. Increase number of max retries or write a shell script which checks if DB2 is free from locks, basically you've to create a dependency, I know this will become bit complicated, there may be better ways to do though.
```

Hope this gives you a better understanding.